# ReactJs Context -- TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting an "Object(...) is not a function" error in my React app

**File: SchemasContext.js**

```
import React, { useState, createContext } from "react";

export const SchemasContext = createContext([]);

export const SchemasProvider = props => {
  const [schemas, setSchemas] = useState([]);

  return (
    <SchemasContext.Provider value={[schemas, setSchemas]}>
      {props.children}
    </SchemasContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

**File: Sidebar.js**

```
import React from 'react';

import { Schemas } from './components.js'
import { SchemasProvider } from "../context/SchemasContext";

console.log('sidebar SchemasProvider: ', SchemasProvider);

function Sidebar() {
  return (
    <SchemasProvider>
      <Schemas />
    </SchemasProvider>
  );
}
```

The `console.log('sidebar SchemasProvider: ', SchemasProvider);` statement seems to confirm that the import is done correctly,  it outputs:

```
sidebar SchemasProvider:  
SchemasProvider(props)
​
length: 1
​
name: "SchemasProvider"
​
prototype: Object { … }
​
<prototype>: function ()
```

And yet I still end up with the errors:

```
Sidebar.js:8
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
SchemasContext.js:5
    SchemasProvider SchemasContext.js:5
    React 22
    js index.js:6
    Webpack 3
The above error occurred in the <SchemasProvider> component:
    in SchemasProvider (created by Sidebar)
    in Sidebar

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit <redacted> to learn more about error boundaries. react-dom.development.js:16764
TypeError: Object(...) is not a functionSchemasContext.js:5
    SchemasProvider SchemasContext.js:5
    React 18
    js index.js:6
    Webpack 3
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The error comes from `useContext` use, you need to show the code related. Usually, it's better to make a reproducible example in a sandbox (like codesandbox).

Comment: @DennisVash, main point: doesn't the `console.log` statement confirm that the imported `SchemasProvider` is a function?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the error, I guess you just don't read the context right with `useContext`

Comment: I've commented out the sections where I call `useContext` but the error persists.  Thank you for your help but I don't think this is the issue.

Comment: I've taken your code, write into a new project, and it causes no issues, please write the fully related code, so we can help,